# Logic error when finding prime numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm receiving a logic error when trying to find all the prime numbers in this array on Codecademy:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class PrimeDirective {
  
  // Add your methods here:
public void findPrime(int[] nums) {
  ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if ((nums[i] % 2 != 0 || nums[i] % 3 != 0 ) || nums[i] % 5 != 0) {
        primeNumbers.add(nums[i]);
        } else { continue; }}
            System.out.println(primeNumbers); }
  
public static void main(String[] args) {
  PrimeDirective pd = new PrimeDirective();
  int[] numbers = {6, 29, 28, 33, 11, 100, 101, 43, 89};
  pd.findPrime(numbers);
  }  
}
```

I expected that if the number is not divisible by either 2, 3, or 5 then it is a prime number. Instead the method is adding all of the array items to the new ArrayList that I initialised in the method.

I expect it is an issue with my maths, but it all makes perfect sense in my head.

Comment: In any case, you may want to look into the difference between `||` (OR) and `&&` (AND). And you may want to look into the rules of prime numbers, because checking divisibility by 2, 3 or 5 is not sufficient.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks for the feedback. What do you mean by the formatting though?

Comment: Your indentation and placement of braces is weird and makes it hard to read your code. I suggest you look at some common Java style guides and follow their suggestions (or use the formatter of your Java IDE).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic error that you are getting in your code is because your condition for checking prime numbers is incorrect. You are only checking if the number is not divisible by 2, 3, or 5, but that is not enough to determine if a number is prime or not. For example, the number 49 is not divisible by 2, 3, or 5, but it is not a prime number either, because it is divisible by 7. A prime number is a number that is only divisible by itself and 1. So, you need to check if the number is divisible by any other number from 2 to its square root. If it is, then it is not a prime number. If it is not, then it is a prime number.

One way to fix your code is to use a boolean variable to keep track of whether the number is prime or not, and use a `for` loop to check all the possible divisors from 2 to the square root of the number. If any of them divides the number without remainder, then set the boolean variable to false and break out of the loop. If none of them does, then set the boolean variable to true and add the number to the `primeNumbers` list. Here is an example of how you can do that:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class PrimeDirective {
    
    // Add your methods here:
    public void findPrime(int[] nums) {
        ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int num : nums) {
            boolean isPrime = true; // assume the number is prime
            if (num == 2) { // special case for 2
                isPrime = true;
            }
            else if (num > 2) { // check numbers greater than 2
                for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) { // loop from 2 to square root of num
                    if (num % i == 0) { // if num is divisible by i
                        isPrime = false; // set isPrime to false
                        break; // break out of the loop
                    }
                }
            }
            else { // handle numbers less than or equal to 1
                isPrime = false; // set isPrime to false
            }
            if (isPrime) { // if isPrime is true
                primeNumbers.add(num); // add num to the list
            }
        }
        System.out.println(primeNumbers); // print the list
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimeDirective pd = new PrimeDirective();
        int[] numbers = {6, 29, 28, 33, 11, 100, 101, 43, 89};
        pd.findPrime(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought it was my "maths" that was failing me.